# How can I install Wine on PureOS?

Tags: wine, pureos, acrobat-reader

I have the [PureOS](https://tracker.pureos.net/w/) with GNOME3 but am having difficulty installing [WINE](https://wiki.debian.org/Wine). I need Wine in order to be able to use [Adobe Acrobat Reader DC](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32266) for my job. I am a rank beginner in Linux, so if someone could walk me through the steps as if teaching a baby I´d really appreciate it! :)
I tried using instructions for Debian, upon which PureOS is based, but it was too complex for me. I don´t know how to use a text editor in Linux.

**Update**:

I used Nano text editor, and, yes, it was incredibly easy to use! I followed the instructions on the WineHQ website for Debian, but this is the message I got:

```
q@q-pc:/etc/apt$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bullseye)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
q@q-pc:/etc/apt$
```

I also tried this command to install Wine:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install wine wine32 wine64 libwine libwine:i386 fonts-wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package wine32 is a virtual package provided by:
winehq-staging 5.0.0~bullseye
winehq-stable 5.0.0~bullseye
winehq-devel 5.0.0~bullseye
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Comment: Unless you use some advanced features in Adobe Acrobat DC I am sure that [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) which you should already have gets your job done.

Comment: Installing Wine is the easy part. Then you need to experiment with help from [AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32266) to make Acrobat work.

Comment: 1) Does PureOS Software Center https://tracker.pureos.net/w/pureos/software_center/ have Wine? 2)  Did you use this command to install WINE  `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install wine wine32 wine64 libwine libwine:i386 fonts-wine`to install Wine?  3) If you have to use a text editor, you may find the nano text editor easy to use. See http://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-nano-text-editor